# How to get latest records from database sorted by id and status

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with these columns: id, status, text.

my sql query: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id AND status DESC`

I need to get all rows from table and sort it by id and by status descending.

result is:

`id | status
1 | 1
2 | 0
3 | 0`

Result should be like this:

`id | status
1 | 1
3 | 0
2 | 0`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use `and` (usually) in the `order by`.  To get the results that you want, you want to order by `status` first, and then the `id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY status DESC, id DESC;
```

Note that `desc` is needed twice, because it applies to only one sort key.

Comment: In the question there was:  sort it by id and by status descending, so ID should be firts, then status, so 'order by is desc, status desc' is more correct.

Comment: @PawelKowalski . . . The sample results are ordered by status first (descending) and then id (descending).

Comment: Yeah, I've just notices... Different result in description and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use DESC for both columns, you are tryitg to sort by:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC,status DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

First add "order by" then add all column by asc/desc order as per sequence:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY status DESC, id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If `status` column is priority, It should be

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY status DESC, id DESC;
```